# How to analyse stream data using computer vision api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-cognitive-services

I am using a Python to input a base64 string and analyze it using the Azure Computer Vision API. How can I format the base64 string to be accepted as a stream file?

**This is where the string is passed:**

```
recognize_printed_results = computervision_client.batch_read_file_in_stream(ImageReqBody['Stream'], raw=True)
```

**This is the error I get**:

```
Exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

**ImageReqBody** is my Json object I use to input the Image String.

What is the format that the `batch_read_file_in_stream()` function can accept?

Comment: Maybe https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode ?

Comment: I am also looking for answer to this question!